# Passing value to modal scope in angular ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form setup in angular and am using ui-bootstrap for a modal dialog that appears before submission is complete. My site is setup in Sharepoint and uses a context to determine if they are on English or Spanish version of the site and display the proper language content. I want to pass the bool value `IsInEnglish` to the modal to display the correct `<div>` but I am not finding a solution to pass this value to the scope of the modal.

```
        $scope.continue = function () { //this is off an ng-click on a button

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '_layouts/Applications/VolunteerApp/modal/myModal.html',
            controller: 'vAppController'
        });

        modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
            $scope.modalIsInEnglish = IsInEnglish;

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `resolve` to `$modal`'s instantiation object:

```
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '_layouts/Applications/VolunteerApp/modal/myModal.html',
        controller: 'vAppController',
        resolve: {
          myVar: function() {
            return someVal;
          }
        }
    });
```

and then pass `someVal` as an argument of the function that invokes the modal:

```
 $scope.continue = function (someVal)
```

To access `someVal` in the modal controller, pass it in as an argument for the modal controller:

```
function myModalController($scope, someVal) { // do stuff }
```

Comment: So, if I was setting that value to an `ng-show` on my modal how would that look? `ng-show="someVal"`?

Comment: Assign `someVal` to a variable that is accessible from the view. If you are using `$scope`, do something like `$scope.showMyElement = someVal`. Then `someVal` will be accessible to the ngShow directive in the view.

Also note the change in my original response. You'll need to pass any value(s) in the resolves into the modal controller as argument(s).

Comment: If my reply helped, any chance you could accept it as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having some frustrations with Plnkr as I am not able to save my plunk. I have a stream and hopefully you can take a look. I am having an issue passing the `someVal` to the modal controller, get an error stating there is no provider for that value. http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=dTJODpQQqFC5dzql

Comment: @Spacemancraig Well, i was in the process of updating your plnkr when something broke and all i get now (even if i create a new plnkr) is an error message about the payload needing to be a string... You had a couple problems 1) `IsInEnglish` was defined in plain ol' Javascript. As such, it is outside of angular's namespace, so the value was undefined, and 2) you weren't passing the `engVar` resolve variable in the modal controllers argument list. Check out my changes and see if they solve your issue.

Comment: I'm off site today working with a dev firm on another project and their wifi went out, fortunately I did see and save the edits you made. I applied that to my solution and that solve my problem!